# Magento Multi Store Admin Redirection issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, multistore

I am working on multistore. i have done all. all working fine. But there is a problem with admin. its redirecting after login to base domain admin domain.com

I am using Code in .htaccess for multiplestore

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)?domain\.us [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:usa]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)?domain\.us [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Is there any way we can separate the both admin panels. if a admin user login in domain.us so he can access only domain.us all feature, not to the base domain.com

please help me regarding this..

One more question. is there any difference of MAGE_RUN_TYPE website and Store?

Comment: can you show as screen shoot of your pproblem?

Comment: Which Type Screenshot u want to see. if we login in domain.us/admin its move to http://www.domain.com/index.php/admin/dashboard/ rather then http://www.domain.us/index.php/admin/dashboard/